# Can I load OGRE's mesh file via direct3d?

Tags: directx, ogre

I just posted this question over at the the OGRE 3D forums, and I wanted to post it here as well.

I'm a newbie here, just found that OGRE is an amazing engine for 3d programming.

Using the Entity class it's easy to load a static model which was exported via some kind of 3ds max plugin.

But I did't read the source-code of OGRE Because I'm not familar with it, and I just got started with OGRE a couple days ago.

So the question is: Does anyone know if I can load a OGRE mesh via d3d?

Or has anyone been doing something using the `OgreEntity.h` and split it out into a separate class which can directly be used in raw direct3d?

I would appreciate if anyone could share some information about the OGRE mesh file format.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to just export the model in a direct3d compatible format? Or convert the existing `.mesh` file.

If you really want to use the OGRE mesh format and load that outside of OGRE, your best bet would be to write your own deserializer. You could use the [MeshSerializer](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1MeshSerializer.html#_details) as a starting-point.